# How can I define a size relative to its parents in Figma?

Tags: figma

I have found the following post but I don't understand the answer, maybe because I am a noob at Figma.

[image]

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure I understand what the problem is here.  If you make a progress bar component, there is nothing to stop you from copying and pasting instances of that component. You can just scale them and the percentage won't change, or you can edit the component, and all instances of that component will update.  Can you show us what you are actually trying to do or what is failing. A screenshot demonstrating your problem would be better. Thanks.

Comment: I've shared a screenshot of what I am talking about [here](https://imgur.com/qC0CRxs). If this is what you are looking for, I can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select the parent object
- Go to the Inspector panel
- Under the Layout section, enable a Layout Grid
- Select the child object
- Set its width and height to be a percentage of the parent's width and
  height

Thus way the child object will keep a consistent size relative to its parent, regardless of any changes made to the parent's size.

Answer (score 0):

A progress bar component is a graphical user interface (GUI) element that is used to display the progress of a task or process.

[image]

If you look at it, it consists of a filled zone - progress and an empty zone - the remaining value.
I think users discussed how many widths should have the progress and empty zone. It is a simple setup in Figma.